# How to fetch the result from database in vtiger crm?

Tags: database, vtiger

I am using vtiger 6.1.0 version.I want to fetch the user details from the database in the vtiger.

My code:

```
require_once('include/database/PearDatabase.php');
$db = PearDatabase::getInstance();
$query8 = "SELECT id from  vtiger_users where is_admin=?";
$result8  =$db->pquery($query8, array("on"));
echo $num_rows = $db->num_rows($result8);

for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) {
  echo $row = $db->query_result_rowdata($result8, $i,'id');
}
```

While using this code, the total number of rows is printed, but each id can not be fetched, showing some internal server error. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only two argument in query_result_rowdata function.
Please see function in include/database/PearDatabase.php file.

```
function raw_query_result_rowdata(&$result, $row=0) {
        if (!is_object($result))
                throw new Exception("result is not an object");
        $result->Move($row);
        $rowdata = $this->change_key_case($result->FetchRow());
        return $rowdata;
    }
```

So please use like that, it work for me.

```
   $index = 0;
 foreach($listViewEntries as $recordId => $record) {
    $rawData = $db->query_result_rowdata($listResult, $index++);
}
```